# Understanding recursive functions calls

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, recursion

Consider the following code:

```
def print_mah(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return
    else:
        print('mah') 
        print_mah(n-1) 

print_mah(3)
```

Here Python checks if n is less than or equal to 0, it finds that this is **False** so it prints 'mah' and calls the same function with n-1 until n is equal to 0, so 'mah' is printed 3 times.

But consider this manipulated code:

```
def print_mah(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return
    else: 
        print_mah(n-1)
        print('mah')

print_mah(3)
```

Python checks if n is less than or equal to 0, it finds that this is **False** so calls the same function again with n-1, and 'mah' is printed 3 times, too.

My question is that why 'mah' isn't printed just one time, in other words why print_mah isn't called with n=2, then Python finds that the condition is **False**, so it calls it with n=1, and finds the condition is **False**, so it calls it with n==0, and finds that the condition is **True**, so the function returns, and after that 'mah' is printed, only, once.

Comment: both versions have the print statement.  One prints it on the way down.  One prints it on the way up. You misread the condition -- it checks to see if the recursion is done.  All other cases involve a print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Python finds that the condition is False, so it calls it with n=1, and finds the condition is False, so it calls it with n==0, and finds that the condition is True, so the function returns

That actually is the exact execution path of the second version. Maybe you don't see, though, that when the function returns it picks back up where it left off **after** the recursive call returns, just like any other method call.

Therefore, when `n==1` and it recurses with `n==0`, then it is returned and `mah` is printed the first time, then that returns and `mah` is printed when `n==2`, then that returns and `mah` is printed a third and final time.

Comment: Oh! You are right, I don't know how have I forgot that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

To understand the different maybe this can help.

**Algorithm 1**

```
def print_n(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return
    else:
        print_n(n-1)
        print(n)
```

**Algorithm 2**

```
def print_n(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return
    else:
        print(n)
        print_n(n-1)
```

These algorithms should provide different results, maybe this is a good starting point for further research.

**Some help**

If you call a function (f2) inside an other function (f1) the current function (f1) will wait until the called function (f2) finished.

**Some keywords for research**

- function call
- stack

Comment: In the first case it should print the numbers from 1 to n in ascending order. But the second algorithm should print them in descending order.

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry! I've made a mistake and typed print(3) instead of print_n(3)

Answer (score 1):

Both functions will print `mah` three times, because you are not **returning** anything after the recursive call. When you call the function inside itself you should handle the stopping condition (which you already did in your first if-condition), then after that it will NOT exit the program because a recursive call builds a stack of operations. After the last operation gets stopped (returns something), then it will start to compile the rest of the function below the recursive call on its way back, until the end of the function is reached.

Answer (score 1):

`return` doesn't break out of your entire call stack, just the current function call. In this case:

```
def print_mah(n):
  if n <= 0:
      return
  else: 
      print_mah(n-1)
      print('mah')

print_mah(3)
```

`print_mah` is called three times before returning 0. You can think about it as if they were just nested logic, like this:

```
def print_mah(n):
  if n <= 0:
      return
  else: 
      print_mah(n-1) # Replace this line with new call
      print('mah')
```

Where we just call the function again inside the else statement at the comment.

```
def print_mah(n):
  if n <= 0:
      #return
  else:
      n = n-1
      if n <= 0:
          #return
      else: 
          print_mah(n-1)
          print('mah')
      print('mah')
```

You can see that print('mah') shows up in sequence at the bottom, which, as it's written, will print sequentially as the functions backtrack out of the call stack.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a "trace" of what the second program is doing:

```
print_mah(3) ->
  print_mah(2) ->
    print_mah(1) ->
      print_mah(0) ->
        # Does nothing, essentially.
        <-
      # print_mah(1) continues running.
      print('mah')  # The last thing that print_mah(1) does.
      <-
    # print_mah(2) continues running.
    print('mah')
    <-
  # print_mah(3) continues running.
  print('mah')
  <-
```

What we see here is that `print('mah')` occurs three times (therefore, 'mah' gets printed three times).

Answer (score 1):

> My question is that why 'mah' isn't printed just one time, in other words why print_mah isn't called with n=2, then Python finds that the condition is False, so it calls it with n=1, and finds the condition is False, so it calls it with n==0, and finds that the condition is True, so the function returns, and after that 'mah' is printed, only, once.

The function only returns out of the most-inner function. The two function levels where the `else` condition is used will then continue execution after the call to `print_mah` and actually print. Here's a line-by-line walk through for `print_mah(2)` for brevity.

```
print_mah(2)
# Enter print_mah - Level 1

    if n <= 0: # n = 2
        # ...
    # False, continue to else

    else: 
        print_mah(n-1)  # n = 2
    # Enter print_mah - Level 2

        if n <= 0: # n = 1
        # ...
        # False, continue to else

        else: 
            print_mah(n-1)  # n = 1
        # Enter print_mah - Level 3

            if n <= 0: # n = 0
                return
            # Return None to print_mah - Level 2

        print('mah')
        # Function is complete, return None to print_mah - Level 1

    print('mah')
    # Function is complete, return None to the execution scope
```